# ActionCable + Devise + Pundit + ApplicationController.render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, pundit, actioncable

I'm trying to render a template in a ActionJob to be broadcast via ActionCable.

```
ApplicationController.render(partial: "messages/message", locals: { message: message }, assigns: { current_user: user}).squish
```

In most instances, this works fine, however some of my templates use Punit for authorization in the view.

```
<% if policy(message).show? %>
  <%= message.body %>
<% end %>
```

This raises an error when the job is ran.

```
ActionView::Template::Error: Devise could not find the `Warden::Proxy` instance on your request environment.
```

A quick Google search reveals this issue: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/4271

The mentioned in the ticket and links, there is no env['warden'] available because no middleware has executed to add it.

How can I work around this?

Comment: Did you check [this](http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/using-action-controller-renderers-in-rails-5-with-devise/) out?

Comment: @ArunKumar Yes, that was one of the links referenced in the ticket.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, this is what I've done:

```
class ActiveJobController < ActionController::Base
end
```

In my partial, instead of using the `policy` helper, I'm doing this

```
<% if Pundit::PolicyFinder.new(message).policy.new(current_user, message).show? %>
  <%= message.body %>
<% end %>
```

and from my `ActiveJob`

```
ActiveJobController.render(partial: "messages/message", locals: { message: message, current_user: user }).squish
```

This avoids any of the stock Devise and Pundit helpers which references  `env["warden"]`. It isn't ideal but works for now both when rendered in a request and in a job.

Answer (score 1):

Another scalable/maintainable approach is to use a helper or a view library like [ViewComponents](https://viewcomponent.org/)/[cells](https://github.com/trailblazer/cells). This way, you can extract your existing view into a component and parameterize any devise/warden methods called in the view. The advantage of this approach is

1. The view is easier to test
2. You can call it from anywhere in your code
3. There are no coupled dependencies

Example using view helpers

Say you have in `app/views/messages/show.html.erb` the following

```
<%= current_user.first_name %>
<%= @message %>
```

Calling `MessagesController.render :show` outside the controller will cause an error since access to the request object is not available. Using ViewComponents, we extract the view into its own component

in `app/components/message_component.rb`

```rb
class MessageComponent < ViewComponent::Base
  def initialize(user:, message:)
    @user = user
    @message = message
  end
end
```

in `app/components/message_component.html.erb`

```
<%= @user.first_name %>
<%= @message %>
```

Usage

In `app/views/messages/show.html.erb` just call

```
<%= render(MessageComponent.new(message: @message, user: current_user) %>
```

In ActionCable, call it like so

```rb
ApplicationController.render(MessageComponent.new(message: @message, user: current_user)
```

Since you have access to `ActiveRecord` models from anywhere in your code, you should be able to fetch `@message`